# fadvise vs madvise? can I use both together?

Tags: c, linux, file, mmap

I'm randomly reading data (each read < page size) throughout a huge file (far too big to fit in memory).

I normally set `MADV_DONTNEED`, but looking at the docs + info it seems I instead need `FADV_NOREUSE`.

I'm not really getting how `madvise()` and `fadvise()` work together. Are they synonymous? Does it matter if I prefer one or the other? Can they be used together? Are they different kernel subsystems? Is `FADV_NOREUSE` what I'm looking for to gain optimal performance?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/fadvise

Answer (score 8):

madvise() and posix_fadvise() are not synonymous. 
madvise() tells the kernel (give advise) what to do with existing memory region while fadvise() tells the kernel what to do with cached (or future cache) of a file data.

For example, if you mmap() anonymous region you should use madvise() to hint the kernal not to swap out (MADV_RANDOM) or to swap out only after access. (MADV_SEQUENTIAL)

If you mmap() a file, or part of a file, you can use either madvise() or fadvise() to hint the kernel to readahead for you (MADV_WILLNEED) or to free that cache (MADV_DONTNEED) or to free after access (POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE, fadvise() only) in additional to the above.

If you use file without mapping the data to your process memory (without using mmap()), you should use fadvise() only. madvise() has no meaning.

As far as kernel subsystem, in linux, it is the same subsystem, simply different ways to refer to memory pages and file cache. Please note that those are only hints and when memory is in dire, the kernel might decide to swap out or reuse cached data despite the hint. Only mlock() and mlockall() can prevent that.

In your case, not giving any hint may help, especially if some pages are being read more than other, since the kernel will figure out which pages are "hot" and will attempt to keep in memory.

Answer (score -2):

If you are only reading from a file then you actually don't need either. The paging daemon will automatically free RAM pages that are associated with non-dirty or shared file-backed mappings. If you keep calling `madvise/MADV_DONTNEED` then you are specifically instructing the kernel to do this. Which may cause performance impact if you access the same page by chance again in the near future.

`fadvise` is only useful if you access your file with `read/lseek`. For `mmap`ped pages it has no effect.

Comment: Such is the theory. Unluckily, Linux has a deliberately broken `MADV_DONTNEED` implementation which will *throw away modified pages*, not only non-dirty ones. `fadvise` works on the buffer cache, which thanks to the unified virtual memory system _does_ affect mapped files. I don't know for certain whether `FADV_DONTNEED` is also broken (never tried), but one can hope. If it works as it should, then it would be greatly useful.

Comment: "If you are only reading from a file then you actually don't need either." -> are you sure about that? I was reading the LKML and it was talking about FADV_NOREUSE for when you are reading chunks from a file you want to copy.

Comment: @AmirTaaki The paging daemon will probably be better at deciding which pages to purge from RAM. And since you are not making them dirty - it has plenty to choose from.